# How to open the additional drivers window using command line

Tags: command-line, drivers, 13.04

How can I launch the **additional drivers** window from the command line?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a terminal, enter the following command:

```
software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
```

- 0 = Ubuntu Software
- 1 = Other Software
- 2 = Updates
- 3 = Authentication
- 4 = Additional Drivers

Comment: A full list of the commands are available by entering `software-properties-gtk -help` in Terminal

Answer (score 10):

The additional drivers window is now incorporated in the **Software & Updates** application in Ubuntu 13.04

It can be launched from the command line (gnome-terminal). Press `Alt F2` to run a command and then type `gnome-terminal` and press `enter`

This will launch a command line.

On the command line type `software-properties-gtk` it will launch **Software & Updates** window, the last tab on that window is the *Additional Drivers* tab.

[image]