# ACER TravelMate 5735Z - How do I update graphic drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics

I'm new to this forum and relatively in Ubuntu.

I've read a lot of forum threads and pages about a problem that occurs with my laptop and Ubuntu: it doesn't go well together (I had Ubuntu 10.04 till yesterday and it worked but I read that they fixed this problem in Ubuntu 14.04, so I installed it and it was only partially solved, which means I could see on the screen but I had to modify the `quiet splash` with nomodeset` in the kernel.)

I would like to know how can I update my graphic drivers, because I read that my laptop model is not supported by the Ubuntu version of the drivers.

- First of all, I would like to know if there is a terminal command to know which graphic card I have.
- Then how can I update the drivers for that graphic card using non-official drivers because official ones seem not to exist.

I'm sorry if I'm asking things you've already explained to a lot of people, but I was unable to find a solution myself in the forum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open the additional drivers window using command line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301543/how-to-open-the-additional-drivers-window-using-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if there is a terminal command to know 
>   which graphic card I have.

You can use [`lspci`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lspci), e.g.:

```
me@my-pc:[~]$ lspci -v | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

> how can I update the drivers for that graphic card using 
>   non-official drivers because official ones seem not to exist.

What do you mean by *non-official*? Proprietary drivers supported by Ubuntu can be found under the *Additional Drivers* tab of the *Software & Updates* dialog:

[image: additional drivers]

Drivers not supported there and which are published as packages can be installed using [APT](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt).