# What is the GPU driver i am currently running?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I have installed latest nVidia graphic driver via this PPA "xorg-edgers/ppa". Now in Nvidia X server setting showing the driver version is 346.35. But in Ubuntu's Additional Drivers there is no such driver rather it marks the Nouveau driver.

I ran `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12`.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] [10de:0e22] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:34fc]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
Memory at fc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
I/O ports at b800 [size=128]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fe780000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 High Definition Audio     Controller [10de:0beb] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:34fc]
```

Which version of graphic driver I am using currently ? If I am not using nVidia's driver then how can I use nVidia's driver.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/22118 http://askubuntu.com/q/301543

Comment: @Tim in my nVidia X Server Settings is showing of my current driver version is 346.35. But in the Additional Driver panel in Ubuntu does not show that driver. Did the 346.35 driver install ?

Comment: Drivers installed from PPAs don't show in Additional Driver panel, and why would they?

Comment: @mikewhatever But in that panel is currently marking the Nouveau driver. Why is that? And how can i sure which driver i am currently running ?

Comment: @MuztabaHasanat: don't cross-post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184854/what-is-the-gpu-driver-i-am-currently-running/184873#184873 !!!  Bad boy!  :P

Comment: @Fabby hahaha. i posted there because in here i was not getting any preferable answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to nVidia's site, they have the linux drivers [here](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us). When you download the driver there will be a readme with instructions. Also, [this askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver) question that is similar to yours has a pretty detailed answer.

Comment: In the nVidia's settings panel is showing that the driver version has been upgraded. But in the additional driver panel of the Ubuntu is marking the Nouveau driver. I want to know am i running Nouveau's driver or nVidia ? Not the procedure of installing driver.